# Can't find path in Minimum Cost Path using Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

- The algorithm is supposed to find the minimum cost path in NxN matrix given as an input. The starting cell is always left bottom and the destination is right top.
- Each cell of the matrix represents a cost to traverse through that cell.
- You can only move up and right.

I have managed to find the cost, however, I still struggle to backtrack the path.

I tried to start from top right cell and use the greedy algorithm to find my "way back", but the output was either completely wrong or skipping random columns/rows. I also tried to keep track of decisions I was making by creating an additional matrix, but I always end up stuck in the loop.

**So how do I find the path?**

Here's the code that works well (counts the cost and that's it):

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int tab[101][101], N, cost[101][101], backtrack[101][101];
    cout << "N (size of NxN matrix) :" << endl;
    cin >> N;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cin >> tab[i][j];
            cost[i][j] = 0;
            backtrack[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    cost[N-1][0] = tab[N-1][0];
    int a = N-1;

     for(int i = N-2; i >= 0; i--)  // column 0 can be chosen only in 1 way
    {
        cost[i][0] = cost[i+1][0] + tab[i][0];
        backtrack[i][0] = 4; // came from down

    }
    for(int j = 1; j < N; j++)  // row N-1 can be chosen only in 1 way
    {
        cost[a][j] = cost[a][j-1] + tab[a][j];
        backtrack[a][j] = 3; // came from right
    }


 for(int i = N-2; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < N; j++)
            {
                if(cost[i][j-1] <= cost[i+1][j])
                {
                    cost[i][j] = tab[i][j] + cost[i][j-1];
                    backtrack[i][j] = 3;
                }

                else
                {
                    cost[i][j] = tab[i][j]+cost[i+1][j];
                    backtrack[i][j] = 4;
                }
            }
        }

   cout << "Cost: " << cost[0][a] << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Now, here's the function with flawed additional matrix that's supposed to give me the path, but ends up in an infinite loop:
(matrix *backtrack* from previous code was given as *track* here)

```
 void path(int track[101][101], int N)
    {
        int help[101][101];
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                help[i][j] = 0;
        }

        int w = 0, k = N-1;

        help[w][k] = 1; // top right argument is included in the output

        while(w < N || k >= 0)
        {
            if(track[w][k] == 3)
            {
                help[w][k-1] = 1; // 3 means I came from the previous column k-1
                k--;
            }
            else if(track[w][k] == 4) 
            {
                help[w+1][k] = 1; //4 means I came from the previous row w+1
                w++;
            }

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if(help[i][j] != 0)
                cout << i << " " << j << endl;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Example input:**

```
    5
    2 3 4 2 5
    5 2 1 2 2
    2 4 2 2 3
    1 2 2 4 3
    3 2 1 2 3
```

**Expected output:**

```
Cost: 20
4 0
4 1
4 2
3 2
2 2
1 2
1 3
0 3
0 4
```

**Actual output**

```
Cost: 20
```

And no path at all since it ends up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve). This is pretty good for a first Question, but could be improved: you don't state the actual output, the input is not hard-coded, the example does not look minimal (does the code work correctly on a 4x4 array?), and you have left it to us to reverse-engineer your algorithm (which can be difficult with code that doesn't work). You'll get an answer, but not as quickly as you could.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an off-by-one error. It is unlikely to be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the `while` loop in `path()` incorrectly:

```
while(w < N || k >= 0)
  ...
```

You intend this loop to continue until w = N-1 and k=0, which it does, but the loop doesn't terminate there, it just runs in place. (You could see this yourself by adding `cout << w << " " << k << endl;` to the loop.) The conditional I think you want is:

```
while(w < N-1 || k > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, after editing it and cout it finally started working properly.